# REACT / AG-GRID: Dynamically setting columnDefs after retrieving data

Tags: reactjs, axios, ag-grid

Within the **componentDidMount()** function, I'm using **AXIOS** to retrieve data and once received, I'm trying to change the column **Header Names** of my **AG-GRID** after retrieving data, but the **Header Names** are unaffected.

Please see line **this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs)** in the following code.

```
var columnDefs = [
    { headerName: "column0", field: "column0", width: 300 },
    { headerName: "column1", field: "column1", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "column2", field: "column2", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "column3", field: "column3", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "column4", field: "column4", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "column5", field: "column5", width: 100 },
];

var PARMS = '';

class Home extends React.Component {
    state = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        header: {},
        isLoading: false,
        error: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        axios.get(API + PARMS)
            .then(fubar => {
                const rowData = fubar.data.results;
                this.setState({ rowData });
                const headerRow = fubar.data.header;
                columnDefs[0].headerName = headerRow.column0;
                columnDefs[1].headerName = headerRow.column1;
                columnDefs[2].headerName = headerRow.column2;
                columnDefs[3].headerName = headerRow.column3;
                columnDefs[4].headerName = headerRow.column4;
                columnDefs[5].headerName = headerRow.column5;

                this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(columnDefs);
            })
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            }));
    }
```

The RENDER() is:

```
render() {
    const { isLoading, rowData, columnDefs } = this.state;

    return (
        <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{ height: '525px', width: '920px' }} >
            <h2>{heading}</h2>

            <AgGridReact
                columnDefs={columnDefs}
                rowData={rowData}>
            </AgGridReact>
        </div>

    );
}
```

I think what the code above is doing (or trying to do):

- Column definitions are defined
- Grid is rendered from Column definitions
- Data is sourced
- Column definitions redefined
- Grid is (or should) rerender

But it isn't happening. In my perfect world, I'd instead like to:

- Retrieve Data
- Define the columns
- Render the Grid

But I'm told "it doesn't work that way".

Answer (score 0):

My solution is two define to Arrays with one set up as a STATE object and the other as a stand alone variable. When the data is refreshed, the stand alone variable is update, and is then used to replace the STATE object.

Is there a better way?

```
var columnDefsNew = [
    { headerName: "", field: "column0", width: 300, },
    { headerName: "", field: "column1", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "", field: "column2", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "", field: "column3", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "", field: "column4", width: 100 },
    { headerName: "", field: "column5", width: 100, }];

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            columnDefs: [
                { headerName: "", field: "column0", width: 300 },
                { headerName: "", field: "column1", width: 100 },
                { headerName: "", field: "column2", width: 100 },
                { headerName: "", field: "column3", width: 100 },
                { headerName: "", field: "column4", width: 100 },
                { headerName: "", field: "column5", width: 100 }],
            rowData: null,
            isLoading: false,
            error: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isLoading: true });

        axios.get(API + PARMS)
            .then(fubar => {
                const headerRow = fubar.data.header;
                const rowData = fubar.data.results;

                this.setState({ rowData });

                columnDefsNew[0].headerName = headerRow.column0;
                columnDefsNew[1].headerName = headerRow.column1;
                columnDefsNew[2].headerName = headerRow.column2;
                columnDefsNew[3].headerName = headerRow.column3;
                columnDefsNew[4].headerName = headerRow.column4;
                columnDefsNew[5].headerName = headerRow.column5;

                this.setState({ columnDefs: columnDefsNew });
            })
            .catch(error => this.setState({
                error,
                isLoading: false
            }));
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoading, rowData, columnDefs } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="ag-theme-balham" style={{ height: '525px', width: '900px' }} >
                <h2>{heading}</h2>

                <AgGridReact
                    columnDefs={columnDefs}
                    rowData={rowData}>
                </AgGridReact>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can able to set dynamic column after retrieve api data by using below function

Here I have used **getColumnDefs() and setColumnDefs()** from gridApi

```
const dynamicallyConfigureColumnsFromObject = (anObject, ticketGridRef) => {
        const colDefs = ticketGridRef.current.api.getColumnDefs()
        const keys = Object.keys(anObject)
        keys.forEach(key => {
            if (colDefs.some(l => l.field === key) === false) {
                colDefs.push({ field: key, filter: 'agTextColumnFilter', headerName: key})
            }
        })
        ticketGridRef.current.api.setColumnDefs(colDefs)
    }
```